# Loading file from resource folder in jar

Tags: jar, wav

I have a .wav file in an audio package.
When I use ..//audio//sound.wav the sound plays when run from the ide but not when run from the jar.
I am sure the audio package is in the jar.
If I put the .wav in the same package as the class it works even from the jar.
How do I get the class to see the audio package when in the jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
Check the jar (open it using winrar) and find the path to your .wav file. Lets say it is PATH...
Now use...

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(PATH);
```

It should work....